# How can I provide a callback function for dismiss buttons in a twitter bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap 3.x and using a modal to show "Are you sure you wish to do this?" type of message with cancel and confirm buttons as shown below.

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you wish to delete this item?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-dismisscallback="deleteCallback">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am also handling the modal hidden event as below.

```js
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  //TODO: invoke callback method if provided
});
```

I've added the additional data-dismisscallback attribute on the Confirm button but not sure how I read and invoke this callback method in the hidden event handler below. Any hint/help to solve this is appreciated.

It does not have to be in this way, any other way to enable a callback mechanism when modal is closed should be acceptable.

Comment: Have you tried adding the event to the callback and checking its relatedTarget? Ex:
$('#modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(e.relatedTarget);
});

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried e.relatedTarget, however it returns "undefined" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events and http://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/issues/224 
I am convinced that the e.relatedTarget is not available out-of-the-box for hide/hidden events. So I have worked out following mechanism, though not as nice, to get solve this problem.

I've removed the data-dismiss attribute while keeping the custom attribute data-dismisscallback to specify a callback function name.

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismisswithcallback="myCallback">Confirm</button>
</div>
```

While in a global event handler, I am closing the modal manually and invoking the callback method.

```js
$("button[data-dismisscallback]").unbind("click").bind("click", function (e) {
    $(this).closest(".modal").hide();

    var callback = $(this).data("dismisscallback");
    if (callback) {
        var fn = window[callback];
        if (typeof fn === 'function') {
            fn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course, this doesn't handle the user dismissing the modal by pressing the Escape key on their keyboard.

Comment: I understand your point, however in this example Escape = Cancel and this is handled by using standard bootstrap data-dismiss attribute and does not need a callback. Thus the usual hidden.bs.modal event should be fired for cancel button and Escape key.

Comment: "data-dismisswithcallback"  in the html and "data-dismiscallback" in the js.  I think these should be the same shouldn't they?